# Auth Web Api with MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt, identity

I have an authorization web api using JWT tokens running on a local IIS, then I have a separate MVC project that requests the token and authentication and gets it but I cant figure out how to use that identity on the Authorize controllers on mvc.

Here are some code to help understanding.

This is where I get my identity on the Web Api

```cs
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");
    oAuthIdentity.AddClaims(ClaimsProviderExtended.GetClaims(user));

    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

In MVC this is my method that I call from the login controller to get the authentication

```cs
public async Task<T> AuthenticateAsync<T>(string userName, string password)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var result = await client.PostAsync(BuildActionUri("/Token"), new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
        }));

        string json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }

//...other code removed for brevity
```

And I now that it creates my identity. But my problem is that in my Home controller I don't pass the Authorize attribute...

Comment: hi, i don't understand - shouldn't your home controller not require authorization so users can reach you login components ?

Comment: My Home controller has my index and I have a separate controller for login and logout.

Comment: right - and you personally know the URL to your login page - your users i assume will need to reach your login form via your home controller - so i'm still not sure what flow you're trying to support by securing your home controller.
BTW  - Default MVC vs tempate doesnt secure it's home controller either

Comment: users will get redirected to the login if they are not authenticated. sorry but I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me about whatever the flow im using, cause for me its the same to put my login on the index controller... my problem is using the web api identity on my mvc app for the authorizes.

Comment: It's not clear what you need. You authenticated the user and obtained a JWT, and then what is the problem? What's the purpose of that JWT inside your MVC project, do you need to access Web API resources from MVC?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I was thinking exactly the same :-)

Comment: Ok, sorry if i didnt explained myself clear. Yes I need access to api resources, but i also need to get authorization for my mvc controller depending on roles. users will only have access to the login and if they get authorized they will enter the main page... my question is whats the best way to authorize the users on my mvc controller?

Comment: MVC-side you will need to store the token somewhere and bind it to some kind of session/cookie. I cannot be more specific because it is a very broad topic, but from what I can see you are not using JWT in the correct way: they are supposed to be used as Bearer Authentication mediums (e.g. used directly from the client).

Comment: i use the token in another angular app, but now i need an mvc app and i need to use the authorize according to the roles assigned in the api.. maybe i need another auth systrm on the api? or i will always need to create an identity on mvc side?